# How to give various properties to cubes in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

Hi I am currently working with three.js, I have created four cubes and I am trying to get (1) texture on one by importing another picture,(2) causing light to reflect from one of the cubes and (3) and making one transparent. I have tried to accomplish this but when I use var texture load, the picture doesnt come on the cube and I really dont understand what is meant that light is reflect from one of the cubes. I think I got the transparency correct. Thank you for any help.

Here the code I have written so far.

```
//declaring  variables
var scene;
var renderer;
var mesh, newMesh;

init();
animate();

//initiating function  to create 4 cubes

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add(light);

    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0033ff , transparent: true, opacity: 0.5});

  // positioning the cubes and adding the necessary texture to them

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );
    mesh.position.z = -50;
    scene.add( mesh );

    newMesh = mesh.clone();
    newMesh.material =new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x050505, color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 70} );
    newMesh.position.x = 50;
    scene.add(newMesh);

  newMesh2 = mesh.clone();
  newMesh2.material =new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0033ff});
    newMesh2.position.y = -25;
    scene.add(newMesh2);

  newMesh3 = mesh.clone();
   var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
//    loader.load("http://www.photoshoptextures.com/sky-textures/blue-sky-texture.jpg",, function(texture) {
//      newMesh3.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture});
    newMesh3.position.x =30 ;
    scene.add(newMesh3) ;


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    render();
}

// ease of rotation so that you can clearly see the image of the cube

function animate() {
    mesh.rotation.x += .04;
    mesh.rotation.y += .02;
    newMesh.rotation.y += .04;
    newMesh.rotation.z += .02;
   newMesh2.rotation.y += .04;
    newMesh2.rotation.z += .02;
  newMesh3.rotation.y += .04;
    newMesh3.rotation.z += .02;


    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
// rendering
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

// setting up the camera

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    render();
}
```

Comment: threejs does not compute inter-object light interactions.

Answer (score 0):

RE: textures - You instantiate a loader with `var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();` but you never use it. Commented code does not execute. But even if it werent commented you have two commas before defining the callback, so it will probably be called onError instead of onLoad.

Whenever you have a question about THREEjs [first look at the reference.](https://threejs.org/docs/)

[Specifically this entry.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader)